# How can I extract all characters between the first / and second / using REGEXP_EXTRACT in Google Data Studio?

Tags: regex, looker-studio

I am trying to use [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) in Google Data Studio for extracting a part of the URL.

Input:

| URLs |
| --- |
| /media/news/royals/meghan-markle-prince-harry-archie-new-photo |
| /marketplace/deals/best-selling-orthotic-friendly-sneakers/ |

Output:

| URLs |
| --- |
| media |
| marketplace |

How can I draft an expression that will allow me to extract it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex & a capture group to find the start of the string, 1 slash, anything not a slash, then a slash. In Python, the regex below works.  Use regex101.com to test your regex.

```
strings = ['/media/news/royals/meghan-markle-prince-harry-archie-new-photo', '/marketplace/deals/best-selling-orthotic-friendly-sneakers/']

for s in strings:
    good_part = re.sub('\A/([^/]*)/.*', r'\1', s)
    print(good_part)
```

prints:

```
media
marketplace
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the following expression: `^/([^/]+)`.

It matches a string that starts (`^`) with `/`, and captures 1 or more characters that are not a `/` after that (`([^/]+)`).

Example:

```sql
WITH URLS AS (
  SELECT '/media/news/royals/meghan-markle-prince-harry-archie-new-photo' url
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '/marketplace/deals/best-selling-orthotic-friendly-sneakers/' url
)
SELECT url, REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, '^/([^/]+)') path
FROM URLS
```

See https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below which extracts all characters between the first `/` and the next `/` (if there is no second `/`, all characters will be captured till the end of the string):

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(URLs, "^/([^/]+)")
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/1fafa6e4-4cff-4d94-a50e-65ffd6c3060e) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JJZ_QTSumNz3F_GPCxAMqsiH739hXJW4eYhzNdMiX0U/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]